# Create a month chooser in Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt

Is there a way to customize or subclass a QCalendarWidget to work as a month chooser?
I would want only the ability to select month/year, it would be ok to show the days but the user shouldn't get the impression he can select them.

I'm developing in PyQt, but answers in c++ are fine.

Comment: you can use a combobox that contain month names.

Answer (score -1):

Try this method

```
void QCalendarWidget::setSelectionMode(SelectionMode mode)
```

Comment: SelectionMode just controls whether or not anything can be selected. I want to select months but not days.

Comment: Do you want month and year are selectable, while date is unselectable?